# How can I achieve a reversed stack of elements in a scrollable container in Google Chrome?

Tags: css, flexbox

I have achieved the effect I desire with the code below, but it only seems to work in Firefox and Edge. In Chrome, the elements are stacked as desired, but there is no horizontal scroll bar so the right most items are hidden and inaccessible to the user.

As you can see, the header and footer stay in place and the my-app element is the only part that is scrollable. The items on the left appear above the ones to the right and the items all the way to the right are available through scrolling.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
}

my-app {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
}

header, footer {
  height: 25px;
  background-color: black;
  color:white;
}

main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  flex-grow: 1;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  margin: 0;
  overflow-x: auto;
  width: 100vw;
}

.card {
  --card-height: 200px;
  --card-width: 250px;

  align-items: center;
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(179, 156, 95, 1), rgba(150, 117, 24, 1));
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 1.5rem 0 2rem #222;
  color: #000;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: var(--card-height);
  justify-content: center;
  min-width: var(--card-width);
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all .15s ease-in-out;
  transition: margin .3s ease-in-out;
  width: var(--card-width);
}

.card:not(:last-of-type) {
    margin-left: calc(var(--card-width) * -.5);
}

.card:hover:not(:last-of-type) {
    margin-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<my-app>
  <header>Header</header>
  <main>
    <div class="card">1</div>
    <div class="card">2</div>
    <div class="card">3</div>
    <div class="card">4</div>
    <div class="card">5</div>
    <div class="card">6</div>
    <div class="card">7</div>
    <div class="card">8</div>
    <div class="card">9</div>
    <div class="card">10</div>
    <div class="card">11</div>
    <div class="card">12</div>
    <div class="card">13</div>
    <div class="card">14</div>
    <div class="card">15</div>
  </main>
  <footer>Footer</footer>
</my-app>
```

If I change the css applied to main to:

```
main {
  ...
  flex-direction: row;
  ...
  justify-content: flex-start;
  ...
}
```

Then the scroll bar appears, but the items aren't stacked correctly(the ones on the right overlay the ones on the left).

If I go one step further and add `direction: rtl;` to the `main` style as well, the layout works as expected, but the default scroll position is all the way to the right of the screen(which makes sense). I could probably keep this and add some javascript to change the scroll location on page load, but that all seems quite hacky. Is there a better way to achieve the layout I'm looking for that will work in Chrome, Firefox and Edge?

Comment: For your stacking order issue with the `row` value, you'll have to assign `z-index` to each card so that the card `n` has a higher z-index than card `n+1`. If your cards are generated in a loop and you know the number of cards, you can add an inline `style="z-index: {{ total - n }}"`. Doesn't solve your entire problem but might get you a tiny bit closer!

Comment: direction + a bit of js to reset the scroll position seems to be indeed what to do now untill chrome's behavior comes in the line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like an additional wrapper solves your problem:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
}

my-app {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
}

header,
footer {
  height: 25px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

main {
  flex-grow: 1;
  margin: 0;
  overflow-x: auto;
  width: 100vw;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.card {
  --card-height: 200px;
  --card-width: 250px;
  align-items: center;
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(179, 156, 95, 1), rgba(150, 117, 24, 1));
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 1.5rem 0 2rem #222;
  color: #000;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: var(--card-height);
  justify-content: center;
  min-width: var(--card-width);
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all .15s ease-in-out;
  transition: margin .3s ease-in-out;
  width: var(--card-width);
}

.card:not(:last-of-type) {
  margin-left: calc(var(--card-width) * -.5);
}

.card:hover:not(:last-of-type) {
  margin-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<my-app>
  <header>Header</header>
  <main>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="card">1</div>
      <div class="card">2</div>
      <div class="card">3</div>
      <div class="card">4</div>
      <div class="card">5</div>
      <div class="card">6</div>
      <div class="card">7</div>
      <div class="card">8</div>
      <div class="card">9</div>
      <div class="card">10</div>
      <div class="card">11</div>
      <div class="card">12</div>
      <div class="card">13</div>
      <div class="card">14</div>
      <div class="card">15</div>
    </div>
  </main>
  <footer>Footer</footer>
</my-app>
```